# What is the difference between N.E. and I in Intel manual?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, instruction-set, instructions

In [Intel's manual for Intel 64 and IA-32 instruction set](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/download/intel-64-and-ia-32-architectures-sdm-combined-volumes-2a-2b-2c-and-2d-instruction-set-reference-a-z.html) section 3.1.1.5, it introduces 64/32-bit mode column in the instruction summary table.

For 64-bit mode support, it says:

> - I - Not supported
> - N.E. - Indicates an instruction syntax is not encodable in 64-bit mode (it may represent part of a sequence of valid instructions in other modes

What is the difference between an instruction is not encodable in 64-bit mode, and an instruction is not supported in 64-bit mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not totally clear exactly what distinction Intel is making, or why it's useful to make that distinction<sup>1</sup>.  It looks like Invalid is only used for opcodes that will #UD (illegal instruction fault), which is why they use N.E. even in cases where there's no *other* way to encode the instruction with that operand-size.

> > N.E. ...  it may represent part of a sequence of valid instructions in **other** modes

This would make sense and I think match their docs if they said "in **this** mode".  e.g. `0x1F` is [not a valid opcode or prefix in 64-bit mode](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html#x1F), but in other modes means `pop ds`.

**Footnote 1**: Of course there's **no future-proof guarantee of faulting with #UD** - a future ISA extension on future CPUs could repurpose unused opcodes for something in 64-bit mode, effectively changing Invalid to N.E.  (The future-proof way to #UD is [the `0F 0B` opcode, documented as `ud2`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ud))

---

**An example of Invalid is [`aam`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/aam) (immediate division) in 64-bit mode**: there's *no* encoding of the instruction at all in that mode, and the opcode is unused.

An example of N.E. is the [`inc r32` short form 0x40+rd](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/inc) which 64-bit mode repurposed (along with 0x48+rd `dec`) as REX prefixes.  `inc eax` is also encodeable, but not with *that* opcode.

Similarly, `inc r/m64` is listed as N.E. for compat/legacy mode; i.e. it's only available in long mode, via a REX prefix.

[`pop`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pop) has examples of both kinds in one table:

- there's no longer any way to do `pop ds` (or ES/SS) with any operand-size, and those opcodes are freed up for future use, so it's "invalid" in 64-bit mode.  (pop cs has never been valid, except for some undocumented / early 8086; only stuff like retf which sets CS:[ER]IP together not just CS.)
- `pop fs` and GS can be done with 16-bit or 64-bit operand-size, but not 32-bit, so the
  "`0F A1  POP FS` ... Pop top of stack into FS; increment stack pointer **by 32 bits**"
  line of the table has N.E. for 64-bit mode, valid for compat/legacy.  And the ... **by 64 bits** line is the reverse, valid for 64, invalid for 32.  (Amusing that they write "by 64 bits" instead of "by 8" when RSP counts in bytes, not bits.)

`pop r32` and `pop r/m32` are both listed as N.E. for 64-bit mode, not invalid, despite the fact that there's no way to encode `pop eax` or `pop dword [rdi]` in that mode.  **So it's looking like Invalid is about the opcode, not the instruction.**

(Even a REX.W=0 doesn't override the operand size to 32-bit for opcodes where the default is 64, but a `66` operand-size prefix does work as usual to make push/pop 16-bit.  This is despite the "description" text saying operand-size may be overridden by REX.W - that seems to be talking about instructions in general, as implied by the current code-segment's D flag.)

Perhaps because 64-bit mode can still pop the other 2 sizes (64 or 16-bit) with the same opcode?  Or the other 2 sizes of r/m with pop?  e.g. `pop ax` and `pop word [rdi]` are valid in 64-bit mode along with `pop rax` of course.

This is consistent with how they listed `pop ds`.

---

I wondered whether [`movsxd r64, r/m32`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movsx:movsxd) would be Invalid or N.E. in 16/32-bit mode, because the same opcode has a different meaning outside of 64-bit mode (ARPL r,r/m16  - http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html#x63).

But instead it's only N.E. for 32-bit mode and **`movsxd r32, r/m32` is listed as "valid" for both modes!**  That has to be a bug because it's obviously wrong.  Opcode `63` in compat/legacy mode is [ARPL](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/arpl).  (Which is listed as N.E. (64) / Valid (32), and whose Operation section mentions movsxd for 64-bit mode.) So N.E. would match their pattern of using that for things which mean something else but don't fault.

(Real-world assemblers like NASM and YASM reject `movsxd eax, ecx` even in 64-bit mode; they want a 64-bit destination, refusing to let you use it as a worse `mov eax, ecx` even though that *is* possible in machine code, but Intel's manual discourages that.  `movsxd` unfortunately needs a REX prefix to serve its only purpose: sign-extend 32 to 64.  Not being a stack or branch op I guess AMD decided it was more consistent for the operand-size to default to 64-bit.)

Comment: `aam` (and similar) are encodable, just not supported/invalid in 64-bit mode. The difference is that a NE instruction is misinterpreted as something else (even if you fooled the assembler into emitting it) while an invalid (again you have to get around the assembler) one throws #UD. It's still unclear to me why instructions like `aaa` or  `aam` are now invalid, possibly to free up some opcode space?

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Yes, I think to free up opcode space, along with push/pop DS/ES/SS. (IDK if that made the decoder hardware more or less complex, as you say there wasn't a real need, and you'd think the same microcode would presumably still have worked in all 3 modes).

Comment: You can still mov to/from those segment regs (with two opcodes for [`mov` to/from Sreg](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov)) but you almost never want to so they freed up that coding space for future use.  IDK why they kept push/pop FS and GS; maybe they hadn't defined the MSRs for controlling their base registers?  Or because those were 2-byte 0F ?? opcodes so were less valuable.

Comment: @MargaretBloom They are neither encodable nor supported.  It's just that the opcode space has not yet been assigned otherwise.  Other instructions (like `arpl`, `bound`, `lds`, and `les`) already have.

Comment: @fuz The whole point of this question (and this answer) is to clarify Intel's terminology: Opcode will be reused => Not supported, #UD and hard failure, Opcode already reused => Not encodable, totally different instruction, silent failure.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: perhaps it would be better to say "not only is `aam` not encodable, the opcode isn't even valid".  i.e. that Invalid is an even stronger thing than N.E. - you can't get the instruction you want this way, *and* it will fault.   I agree with fuz that it doesn't really make sense to say it's actually encodeable.  I mean sure you can use the same encoding that's valid in other modes, and it hasn't been repurposed.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I never thought about it that way... I always thought N.E. means “this encoding doesn't exist but the instruction is valid in other encodings” while I means “this instruction isn't supported at all in this mode.”

Comment: It's a weird thing to document as "invalid" - for prefixes which don't apply, Intel is always clear that the meaning can change for future CPUs.  But **these "Invalid" opcodes don't have any future-proof guarantee of faulting** - a future ISA extension could repurpose them for something in 64-bit mode.  (Unfortunately all current extensions have been 32 and 64-bit, e.g. VEX (AVX) and EVEX (AVX-512) prefixes are invalid encodings of existing instructions in 32-bit mode, leaving that more compact coding space of push/pop Sreg or the BCD instructions unused.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Technically speaking, the extensions also work in 16 bit mode, just not in real mode or virtual 8086 mode.  Not sure if you can use them from SMM mode though.

Comment: @fuz N.E. means that if you intend to get that, you will always get something else (the 64 bit instruction), typically when the 64 bit instruction doesn't require a rex byte to distinguish. I means that if you intend to get that, you will get an #UD, and N.S. means that the instruction requires an address override prefix, which has undefined behaviour in long mode

Comment: @LewisKelsey: `67` address-size prefix is totally well-defined in long mode; `gcc -mx32` (x32 ILP32 ABI in long mode) uses it frequently.  Also, I think you're being too specific about what N.E. means; you get *something* other than #UD, but for example 0x40+rd `dec r32` is listed as N.E.  But in 64-bit mode it behaves *as a rex prefix*, modifying the *next* instruction to maybe use different registers, as well as a different size (for dec, not inc). I forget what happens with two different inc/dec instructions back-to-back (2 rex prefixes); probably still not #UD, just no documented behaviour

Comment: @PeterCordes I didn't word that very well. I mean't 64-bit long mode, and I mean't it has undefined behaviour when used with that instruction in 64-bit long mode, but I'm not sure why you can with some instructions and not others. You can with `pop r/m16` but not with `jmp r/m16` or `call rel16`

Comment: @LewisKelsey: For `call rel16`, the rel16 would be the operand-size, not the address-size.  Not sure about `jmp r/m16`, I don't think 16-bit operand-size would be possible, but you can certainly use `jmp qword [esi]` if you want; A `67` *address-size* prefix basically means the offset part of the memory address is truncated to 32-bit.  I forget if there is any effect on how JMP updates RIP, but probably not; I think that would again be operand-size not address-size.